# Как заставить Systemd запускать скрипт после запуска OpenVPN?

Tags: linux, openvpn, systemd

В общем, пытаюсь выполнить скрипт с помощью сервиса. Так не рабоатет почему то:

```
[Unit]
Description=Description
After=network.target
After=openvpn.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/path_to_dir/script.sh --flag param
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Вот, что пишет:

```
tun0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
my_script.service: Succeeded.
```

Содержимое `openvpn.service`:

```
# This service is actually a systemd target,
# but we are using a service since targets cannot be reloaded.

[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecReload=/bin/true
WorkingDirectory=/etc/openvpn

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: *my_script.service: Succeeded* — противоречит вашему утверждению про «не работает».

Comment: Такой вывод. Скрипт то срабатывает. Но в скрипте нужно наличие устрйоства `tun0`. Мне нужно, что бы скрипт запускался после подъема VPN.

Comment: Покажите как вы запускаете openvpn (файл сервиса)

Comment: Судя по `ExecStart=/bin/true` - кажется, вы указали какую-то неправильную зависимость. Поищите другую...

Comment: ну и вообще вы не с той стороны взялись за задачу. вам ведь не запуск демона нужен, а факт установки соединения. а о том, что соединение установлено, systemd даже теоретически узнать не сможет. [надо с другого конца подойти](https://askubuntu.com/q/28733/416190).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin systemd теоретически как раз всё прекрасно узнать может, через sd_notify (и openvpn этим даже пользуется на практике, но я не до конца понял в какой момент времени)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, решил проблему просто добавив в начало скрита небольшой цикл:

```
while true
do
    ip l | grep tun0 > /dev/null

    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
    then
        break
    else
        sleep 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: Костыль. Кажется, вы так и не разобрались, как же у вас всё-таки запускается openvpn